# SED and Reg Exp

Tags: regex, sed

i want to print areas (more then one line) that starts with "if($EN)" and end with "?>"
I want to use sed - but I'm open to an other solution

first approach:

```
cat modal_27001.inc.php |  sed -n '/if/,/?>/p'
```

is working but gives me also lines starting with e.g. if($ABC)

the following ist **not** working , and i don't know why

```
cat modal_27001.inc.php |  sed -n '/if\(\$EN\)/,/?>/p'
```

Can somebody tell me why?

thanks rob

edit: 
here is a short testfile
i want to extract the first 8  lines (but ther are not always the first 8)

```
<?php
   if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
   ?>
<?php
   if ($BCD) {
    echo "Hemad san Servas. Großherzig gscheckate";                             
    echo "Jodler Kuaschwanz wiavui,";                           
    echo "Watschnbaam resch Sauwedda, i mog di";                            
    echo "Brotzeit Guglhupf sammawiedaguad ";                           
   }
   ?>
<?php
echo "02397450923754ß3258764ß95867"
?>
```

the result should be

```
   if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
 ?>
```

or even better:

```
<?php
   if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: try without escaping the parenthesis  `sed -n '/if(\$EN)/,/?>/p'` as by default sed uses BRE where parenthesis are not meta characters

Comment: You are using POSIX BRE regex, so, the literal `(` should be defined as a `(` in the pattern, not `\(`. Also, sed operates on lines be default. See [How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string)

Comment: could you put some context that you want to be match?

Comment: @sundeeb - there is no change in the result ...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  (using the testfile above)
cat test.txt | sed -n "/if(/,/?>/p" gives me no result
cat test.txt | sed -n "/if/,/?>/p" gives me line 2  to 8 and 10 to 16 - almost what i want

Comment: @k-five i add an example to the question

Comment: damm i forgot the space - cat test.txt | sed -n "/if (\$EN/,/?>/p" -
Can someone tell me how i can add the line above the match also?

Comment: @robkuhlig, Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume you only want to print your match, since you said: *i want to print areas (more then one line) that*

First of all this regex:

## [if(?:\s+)?(\$EN).*?\?>](https://regex101.com/r/IJ0v0t/1)

can match what you want.
But if you want to print it, I know little with **sed**, but still I can solve   this task with **Perl**

Say you have this file:

```
if ($BCD) {
    echo "Hemad san Servas. Großherzig gscheckate";                             
    echo "Jodler Kuaschwanz wiavui,";                           
    echo "Watschnbaam resch Sauwedda, i mog di";                            
    echo "Brotzeit Guglhupf sammawiedaguad ";                           
   }
   ?>
<?php
echo "02397450923754ß3258764ß95867"
?>
<?php
   if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
   ?>
if ($BCD) {
    echo "Hemad san Servas. Großherzig gscheckate";                             
    echo "Jodler Kuaschwanz wiavui,";                           
    echo "Watschnbaam resch Sauwedda, i mog di";                            
    echo "Brotzeit Guglhupf sammawiedaguad ";                           
   }
   ?>
<?php
echo "02397450923754ß3258764ß95867"
?>
<?php
   if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
   ?>
<?php
   if ($BCD) {
    echo "Hemad san Servas. Großherzig gscheckate";                             
    echo "Jodler Kuaschwanz wiavui,";                           
    echo "Watschnbaam resch Sauwedda, i mog di";                            
    echo "Brotzeit Guglhupf sammawiedaguad ";                           
   }
   ?>
<?php
echo "02397450923754ß3258764ß95867"
?>
```

There is more than one match for your pattern, and simply you can print it, if you want just **once**
`perl -lne ' $/=undef;/\s+if(?:\s+)?\(\$EN\).*?\?\>/s && print $&' file`

**the output**

```
    if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
   ?>
```

Or more than one times:
`perl -lne ' $/=undef; print $& while /\s+if(?:\s+)?\(\$EN\).*?\?\>/gs' file`

**the output**

```
    if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
   ?>

    if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
   ?>
```

Also for your

> even better

```
perl -lne ' $/=undef; print $& while /\<\?php(?:\s+)?if(?:\s+)?\(\$EN\).+?\?\>/gs' file
```

**the output**

```
<?php
   if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
   ?>
<?php
   if ($EN) {
    echo "Watschnpladdla Wurscht Vergeltsgott gscheckate ";                             
    echo "Bua pfenningguat Semmlkneedl";                            
    echo "Blosmusi heitzdog nia Edlweiss Sauakraud";                            
    echo "Milli, des is schee i mechad ";                           
   }
   ?>
```

### Prove

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In many `sed` dialects, you *don't* backslash the parentheses.

Also, the [`cat` is useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).

```
sed -n '/if(\$EN)/,/?>/p' modal_27001.inc.php
```

Many `sed` dialects also have an option like `-E` or `-r` to enable extended (aka "modern") regular expressions, but what exactly that means and what the option is called depends on the version of `sed`.